# Node.js returning an API response within an async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have written the following code to retrieve song lyrics from the apiseeds lyric api.

```
const apiseeds = require("apiseeds-lyrics");
const apiseedskey = "MY_API_KEY";

async function getLyrics(artistName, songName)
{
    return await apiseeds.getLyric(apiseedskey, artistname, songName, 
    (response) => {
        return response;
    });
}


var artist = "Darius Rucker";
var title = "Wagon Wheel";
var lyrics = await getLyrics(artist, title)
console.log(lyrics);
```

I should also mention that the second block of code there is enclosed within an eventEmitter.on event with an asynchronous callback function.

Whenever the code runs, I get `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` and `await` can only be used to treat asynchronous functions that returns Promises, not callbacks. You should be able to transform your call to use Promises, or use another library.

The main reason we use `await` is to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing the code execution:

```
const result = await codeThatReturnsPromise()
console.log(result)
```

We could transform your code to this:

```
// async here means it returns a promise
async function getLyrics(artistName, songName)
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    apiseeds.getLyric(apiseedskey, artistname, songName, (response) => resolve(response))
  })
}

var artist = "Darius Rucker";
var title = "Wagon Wheel";
var lyrics = await getLyrics(artist, title)
console.log(lyrics);
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can transform my call to return a Promise?

Comment: Yes, you can use `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ... resolve(value))`, so you call the resolve callback with the data provenient from your callback function.

Comment: Added to answer